# Escalas de colores para geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

Intento crear un gráfico ternario `ggtern(data = Libro1,x= Arcilla, y= Arena, z= MO)` y utilizar `geom_point` para representar con puntos y escalas de colores los diferentes `Largos de planta` obtenidos sobre el gráfico ternario. El problema es que por ser puntos no me permite utilizar la función `scale_colour_gradient2` que sería la ideal para el tipo de representación que busco, con una escala de rojo, amarillo y verde representando el `Largo de planta` obtenido para visualizar donde se encuentran las mayores producciones dependiendo el tipo de suelo.

Copio a continuación la función con la que estoy trabajando y resultados obtenidos:

```
> ggtern(data = Libro1, aes(x= Arcilla, y= Arena, z= MO))+
  Tlab('Arena')+Llab('Arcilla')+Rlab(expression(paste('MOx10'^-1))) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = factor(Largo)))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como ven en el gráfico anterior, se presentan todos los datos uno por uno con un color diferente. El resultado que espero obtener es una escala de colores con representación del valor de los datos con máximo en verde, medio en amarillo y mínimo en rojo.

He intentado con otras funciones como por ejemplo `alpha`o `geom_point(aes(colour = (Largo))`, pero no he logrado el resultado esperado.

Cualquier recomendación o comentario será de mucha ayuda, muchas gracias!

Comment: por que usas `factor`? Intentaste con `geom_point(aes(colour = Largo))`? El segundo gráfico no poden los puntos donde esperas pues no pusiste ninguna variable dentro del `aes`. Te sugiero que estudies más ejemplo de ggplot2 ;)!

Comment: Si, he intentado con 'geom_point(aes(colour = Largo))' pero no me da el resultado que espero. He estudiado los libros de ggplot2, pero no encuentro ejemplos similares a mi situación. Me disculpo por el segundo ejemplo, falta de atención allí de mi parte. Te agradezco por tu tiempo, un saludo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar, en el segundo gráfico solo estás dibujando los puntos que caen en la escala del negro absoluto, por eso te ves solo algunos. Lo que puedes hacer, es usar alguna de las paletas de colores ya definidas como [`terrain.colors(n)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/palettes.html), en este caso le defines el número de colores de la muestra:

```
library(ggtern)
df = data.frame(Arena = runif(100),
                Arcilla = runif(100),
                MO = runif(100),
                Largo = runif(100))

ggtern(data = df, aes(x=Arena, y=Arcilla, z=MO)) +
    Tlab('Arena') +
    Llab('Arcilla')+
    Rlab(expression(paste('MOx10'^-1))) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = Largo)) +
    scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rev(terrain.colors(100)))
```

Esto te generaría un gráfico más cercano a lo que buscas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Toma nota, que revertimos el orden de la paleta para que los valores altos tiendan al verde y los bajos al naranja. Ahora si quieres una paleta más "exacta" a lo que pides, puedes crearla usando [`colorRampPalette()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/colorRamp.html)

```
colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow", "green"))
```

Y luego para generarla, estableces la cantidadad de colores:

```
paleta <- colfunc(100)
```

Ahora simplemente configurando esta paleta en el gráfico:  `scale_colour_gradientn(colours = paleta)` obtendremos algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Patricio!! Es exactamente lo que buscaba